# Firebase php limit action

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase php sdk library. I cannot set the start and end limit of the data I will withdraw. I will call data 5 with example 10. How can I do that?

```
$this->fdb->getReference($ref)->limitToFirst(5)->limitToLast(10)->getValue();
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can never combine `limitToFirst` and `limitToLast` clauses in Firebase Realtime Database.

If you want to get a slice in the middle of the potential data, you will need to know the key of the node to start and/or end at and use `startAt` and/or `endAt`.

For example, if you're implementing pagination, you need to remember the key of the last node of the first page, and pass that in `startAt(lastKeyOfFirstPage)` (or `startAfter(lastKeyOfFirstPage)` if that's available in your SDK) as the starting point for the next page of results.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**start form the key from where you want where and end that before your +1 key of last key**

**startAt**

```
$database->getReference('people')
    // order the reference's children by the values in the field 
    'height'
    ->orderByChild('height')
    // returns all persons taller than or exactly 1.68 (meters)
    ->startAt(1.68)
    ->getSnapshot();
```

**endBefore**

```
$database->getReference('people')
    // order the reference's children by the values in the field 'height'
    ->orderByChild('height')
    // returns all persons shorter than 1.98 (meters)
    ->endBefore(1.98)
    ->getSnapshot();
```